# Failed to install tensorflow with Ubuntu 16.04 and CUDA 8.0

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

Does anyone successed install TensorFlow with following combination?

- Ubuntu 16.04 (Just newly installed and apt upgraded)
- Nvidia Driver: nvidia-370 (sudo apt install nvidia-370)
- Bazel 0.3.1 (install from official package):

  ```
  chmod +x bazel-0.3.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
  ./bazel-0.3.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
  ```
- gcc: 5.4.0 (default with 16.04)
- CUDA 8.0.44 (for GTX 1070, installed from official .run file without driver)

  ```
  export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
  export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- cuDNN 5.1.5 (installed from official package)
- tensorflow master (clone from official github)
- python 2 and python 3 (install from ubuntu official source)

Then run the tensorflow/configure:

```
./configure
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: /usr/bin/python3
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] N
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] 
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GPU support? [y/N] y
GPU support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: 
Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 8.0
Please specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system default]: 5.1.5
Please specify the location where cuDNN 5.1.5 library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size.
[Default is: "3.5,5.2"]:
```

and run the building:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda
```

some error occured immediately:

```
ERROR: /home/devymex/.cache/bazel/_bazel_devymex/05af4cc48fb50d1cc8f7e879f4c1ce83/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD:4:1: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/devymex/.cache/bazel/_bazel_devymex/05af4cc48fb50d1cc8f7e879f4c1ce83/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD", line 4
        error_gpu_disabled()
    File "/home/devymex/.cache/bazel/_bazel_devymex/05af4cc48fb50d1cc8f7e879f4c1ce83/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/error_gpu_disabled.bzl", line 3, in error_gpu_disabled
        fail("ERROR: Building with --config=c...")
ERROR: Building with --config=cuda but TensorFlow is not configured to build with GPU support. Please re-run ./configure and enter 'Y' at the prompt to build with GPU support.
...
```

I've tried to:

- reinstall Ubuntu, many times;
- reinstall Bazel (from 3party source), many times too.
- try different Bazel version (0.3.1, 0.3.0, frome official packages)
- switch to the older CUDA version 8.0.27 (CUDA 7 doesn't support GTX 1070)
- try different cuda paths "/usr/local/cuda" and "/usr/local/cuda-8.0" (all of them are exist)
- re-run ./configure many times and re-run bazel build -c opt --config=cuda
- run "bazel clean" before re-run ./configure
- re-download offical tensorflow package or re-clone official tensorflow github repo
- delete path ~/.config/bazel before ./configure
- python2 and python3
- I've tried all possible action that may related to this error.

but the error always occured and with identical message.

I've try to use tensorflow r0.10 package (download from git hub), the error message were became to:

```
ERROR: no such package '@local_config_cuda//crosstool': BUILD file not found on package path.
ERROR: no such package '@local_config_cuda//crosstool': BUILD file not found on package path.
```

with the tensorflow r0.10, above tried actions has no effect to these two error message.

I'm so frustrated after four days failure. Does someone could help me? Thanks!

I also posted this issue to github:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2559

Comment: CUDA 8 was literally released days ago. Are you *really* sure tensorflow has support for CUDA 8

Comment: As far as I know, the CUDA 8.0.27 has been released for several months.

Comment: The release candidate had been publically  available since late May. But the official release only happened within the last couple of weeks. The date is irrelevant. Do you know for sure that CUDA 8 is supported?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure whether CUDA 8 is supported in the official story, but there are so many people show their successful installation of tensorflow with CUDA 8, and my GTX 1070 doen't support CUDA 7.5.

Comment: I just installed it and it works fine. One thing you need to do is patch the crosstool file: https://marcnu.github.io/2016-08-17/Tensorflow-v0.10-installed-from-scratch-Ubuntu-16.04-CUDA8.0RC-cuDNN5.1-1080GTX/ (it is named slightly differently now in tensorflow master, I think CROSSTOOL.tpl) but that does not seem like errors that you have. Maybe you want to clean ~/.cache before running configure.

Comment: The patch does not work too and occured the same error. Furthermore, I always deleted the path ~/.cache/bazel before run ./configure.

Comment: I can confirm this setup, at 2016.12.26 I am running Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 8.0.44, NVIDIA x86_64-375.26 drivers With Dual GTX 980Ti GPUs, CuDNN 5105, CNMeM. Gcc version 5.4.0,
Using it with Keras on both backends TensorFlow and Theano.
I did not use Bazel. Just install drivers and Cuda with .run option.